# How prove this $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}r_{p}(k^2+k)=\frac{p^2-p}{2}$

Tags: number-theory

> let $r_{n}(m)$ be the remainder of the division of $m$ by $n$ ,and $p$ is a prime congruent to 7 modulo 8.
>
> show that
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}r_{p}(k^2+k)=\dfrac{p^2-p}{2}$$

my idea: let $$k^2+k\equiv j\pmod p\Longrightarrow (2k+1)^2\equiv 4j+1\pmod p$$

Answer (score 1):

Note: There may or may not be a neater way to finish this problem. Below, I approach the problem by converting to standard sums for which I already know results for.

---

**Step 1:** Convert to sums involving Legendre symbol

Note $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{r_p(k^2+k)}=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}{r_p(k^2+k)}$$

$$k^2+k \equiv j \pmod{p} \Leftrightarrow (2k+1)^2 \equiv 4j+1 \pmod{p}$$

The congruence $x^2 \equiv a  \pmod{p}$ has $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)+1$ solutions $\pmod{p}$ in general, so the congruence $x^2 \equiv 4j+1 \pmod{p}$ has $\left(\frac{4j+1}{p}\right)+1$ solutions $\pmod{p}$.

Each solution for $x$ corresponds to a solution for $k$ to $(2k+1)^2 \equiv 4j+1 \pmod{p}$ via $k \equiv (x-1)2^{-1} \pmod{p}$, so there are exactly $\left(\frac{4j+1}{p}\right)+1$ solutions for $k \pmod{p}$ to $(2k+1)^2 \equiv 4j+1 \pmod{p}$, and hence to $k^2+k \equiv j \pmod{p}$.

Thus 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{r_p(k^2+k)}&=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}{r_p(k^2+k)}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}{j\left(\left(\frac{4j+1}{p}\right)+1\right)}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}{j\left(\left(\frac{j+\frac{p+1}{4}}{p}\right)+1\right)} \\
&=\frac{p^2-p}{2}+\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}{j\left(\frac{j+\frac{p+1}{4}}{p}\right)} 
\end{align}

It remains to show $$\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}{j\left(\frac{j+\frac{p+1}{4}}{p}\right)}=0$$

---

**Step 2:** Convert to sums involving $i\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)$

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}{j\left(\frac{j+\frac{p+1}{4}}{p}\right)}&=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{3p-5}{4}}{j\left(\frac{j+\frac{p+1}{4}}{p}\right)}+\sum_{j=\frac{3p-1}{4}}^{p-1}{j\left(\frac{j+\frac{p+1}{4}}{p}\right)} \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{3p-5}{4}}{j\left(\frac{j+\frac{p+1}{4}}{p}\right)}+\sum_{j=\frac{3p-1}{4}}^{p-1}{j\left(\frac{j-\frac{3p-1}{4}}{p}\right)} \\
&=\sum_{i=\frac{p+1}{4}}^{p-1}{\left(i-\frac{p+1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}+\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(i+\frac{3p-1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)} \\
&=\sum_{i=\frac{p+1}{4}}^{p-1}{\left(i-\frac{p+1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}+\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(i-\frac{p+1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}+p\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)} \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{\left(i-\frac{p+1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}+p\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)} \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{i\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}-\frac{p+1}{4}\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}+p\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}
\end{align}

---

**Step 3:** Evaluation of sums.

Since there are exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ nonzero quadratic residues, 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}=0$$

It remains to show that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{i\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}=-p\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}$$

Since $p \equiv 7 \pmod{8}$, $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=-1$ and $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=1$. Thus:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{i\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)} &=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}{2j\left(\frac{2j}{p}\right)}+\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-3}{2}}{(2j+1)\left(\frac{2j+1}{p}\right)} \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}{2j\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)}+\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-3}{2}}{(2j+1)\left(\frac{j+\frac{p+1}{2}}{p}\right)} \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}{2i\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}+\sum_{i=\frac{p+1}{2}}^{p-1}{(2i-p)\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)} \\
&=2\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{i\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}-p\sum_{i=\frac{p+1}{2}}^{p-1}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)} 
\end{align}

Thus 
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{i\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}&=p\sum_{i=\frac{p+1}{2}}^{p-1}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)} \\
&=p\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}-p\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)} \\
&=-p\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)} \\
&=-p\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}-p\sum_{i=\frac{p+1}{4}}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}
\end{align}

It remains to show 
$$\sum_{i=\frac{p+1}{4}}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}=0$$

Indeed, we have

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=\frac{p+1}{4}}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)} &=\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}-\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)} \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{2j}{p}\right)}+\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{2j+1}{p}\right)}-\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)} \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)}+\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{j+\frac{p+1}{2}}{p}\right)}-\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)} \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{j+\frac{p+1}{2}}{p}\right)} \\
&=-\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-3}{4}}{\left(\frac{\frac{p-1}{2}-j}{p}\right)} \\
&=-\sum_{j=\frac{p+1}{4}}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}
\end{align}

so

$$\sum_{j=\frac{p+1}{4}}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}{\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)}=0$$

as desired.

---

Finally combining everything gives the desired result, $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{r_p(k^2+k)}=\frac{p^2-p}{2}$$